# Autofac - Create new instance of class when another class is resolved

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm using Autofac and have a `QuizManager` which has an event. The `QuizManager` is responsible for creating and handling different quizes. The lifetime of this class is transient, so it will have several instances.

```
public class QuizManager : IQuizManager
{
    // Other methods...

    public event Action<string> OnQuizStarted;
}
```

Every time one instance of this class is resolved I want another class to subscribe to it's event. This is because I have *"chained"* logic that should occur every time a quiz is started. In particular it should send an event to a SignalR hub. I do not want this logic in my `QuizManager`. For other reasons I cannot register `QuizManager` as a singleton. `QuizManager` is injected in constructor at several other classes.

Below is a class that subscribes to the event in `QuizManager`.

```
public class QuizHubInvoker
{
    public QuizHubInvoker(IQuizManager quizManager)
    {
        quizManager.OnQuizStarted += OnQuizStarted;
    }

    private void OnQuizStarted(string quizToken)
    {
        // Do logic here every time event is invoked.
        // It actually invokes a method in a SignalR Hub.
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can subscribe to an event of a class, which has a transient lifetime?

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905944/how-to-wire-events-with-methods-using-autofac) help?

Comment: @stuartd - It looks promising. I will try it. Thank you.

Comment: @stuartd - It gave me a working solution. What should I do with my question? Do you want to write up an answer? Or should I? Or should I mark it a duplicate?

Comment: I think duplicate is best.

Comment: @stuartd - Cool. Thanks again!